# What are the standards behind realtime web?

Tags: standards, real-time, comet

I'm looking for standards that are behind realtime web applications.
I know about W3C Websockets API and IETF Websockets protocol, Bayeux protocol and Server-Sent Events standards.
Are there any other standards for techniques like long-polling, callback-polling, Iframe streaming, htmlfile streaming, XHR streaming, multipart streaming, Direct Socket?

Comment: Maybe this can help you out: http://www.w3viewer.com

Answer (score 1):

Long polling doesn't have a dedicated standard. It is effectively an implementation technique layered on top of existing standards like HTTP and [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) (which is standardized as W3C working drafts). The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) page is a pretty good reference.

XMPP standardizes a technique called [BOSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOSH) which is also implemented as long-lived HTTP.

multipart/x-mixed-replace was implemented by Netscape but not IE, and is not a standard. The [Push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) Wikipedia page is a good reference.

Hope these help.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in a Java implementation I just wrote a sample app and a blog post about it. It uses Java, Maven, Comet, Bayeux, Spring. 
http://jaye.felipera.cloudbees.net/ 
http://geeks.aretotally.in/thinking-in-reverse-not-taking-orders-from-yo

Answer (score 0):

I have found an interesting answer on quora (http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-standards-behind-realtime-web) :

The following protocols are core to the Realtime Web:

1. HTTP protocol in general makes so much possible WebSockets protocol
2. [PubSubHubbub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/PubSubHubbub) protocol
3. Webhooks eXtensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP) & BOSH
   (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0...)
4. Activity Streams (as pointed
   out by Chris Saad)
5. [http-live-streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-live-streaming) / HTTP Long-Polling